# How to downgrade or upgrade AuditD on redhat 8

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, auditd, system-calls

**OS version** = Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
**Kernel version** = 4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64

I can't find a way to upgrade/downgrade `auditd` or `auditctl`.

I must change the version of the `auditd/auditctl`.  It doesn't matter to what version.  At the moment I am using version **3.0.7**.

FYI - there are no packages that are called `auditd` or `auditctl`

Comment: The package you search for is `audit`. The old version of the package is for kernel 2.x. What is the reason to want change of version?

Comment: My suggestion is go upstream to a later RHEL release, export the package, then import it. You can use a VM to accomplish this task.